# Cordova android app not communicating with server

Tags: cordova

I have a Cordova app built on Cordova 11.0

It uses the following platform versions

- android 10.1.2
- browser 6.0.0
- ios 6.3.0

It users the following plugins

- cordova-plugin-android-permissions 1.1.5 "Permissions"
- cordova-plugin-device 2.1.0 "Device"
- cordova-plugin-file 7.0.0 "File"
- cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.1.0 "Geolocation"
- cordova-plugin-statusbar 3.0.0 "StatusBar"
- cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr 3.1.0 "Cordova WKWebView File XHR Plugin"

config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="id" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <name>name</name>
    <description>desc</description>
    <author email="my@email.com">
        whiz bang development
    </author>
    <icon src="res/icon.png" />
    <preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />
    <content src="index.html" />
    <platform name="android">
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
        <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
    </edit-config>
    </platform>
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" /> 
    <allow-intent href="*" />
</widget>
```

I was under the impression the above would eliminate CORS as a problem.

However, when I run in the browser, the console shows me the errors

jquery-1.11.1.js:9624 Refused to set unsafe header "Origin"

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://11.111.111.111:8081/service' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

POST http://11.111.111.111:8081/service net::ERR_FAILED

The failing bit of code is

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                timeout: 30000,
                crossDomain: true,
                headers: { 'Access-Control-Request-Methods': 'POST',
                           'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                           'Origin': 'http://localhost:8000'},
                url: options.server + "/service",
                data: JSON.stringify(param),
                success: function (msg) {
                    //rejoice
                },
                error: function (x, t, m) {
                    console.log("error getting results x=" + JSON.stringify(x) + " t=" + t + " m=" + m);
                }
            });
```

The error produced is

"error getting results x={"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"} t=error m="

When I open the browser as follows

`open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --user-data-dir="/var/tmp/chrome-dev-disabled-security" --disable-web-security --disable-site-isolation-trials`

I do NOT get any of the errors.

When I run on Android I get the error message:

"error getting results x={"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"} t=error m="

I had thought changing stuff so it would run in the browser  would fix the problems in Android but I was wrong.

How do I make this work in Android?

Comment: it worked for android, although I needed all 3 of the android entries in my config.xml.  thank you!